# Inlining CSS NodeJS Server

Tags: css, reactjs, server, inline

I've recently gotten into the server side of NodeJS and I've noticed that importing styles and automatic in-lining no longer works. When I keep my SCSS file imported, my server is unable to start and can't parse it. Does anyone know how to restore the regular frontend behavior for css inlines.

I initially imported my SCSS via `import styles from '../css/style.scss';` and it worked perfectly and inlined itself in the HTML document.

I'm using webpack to compile my SCSS into hashed CSS.
My config:

```
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
require('babel-register');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/app.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/src/js/",
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    mode: 'development',
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                cache: true,
                parallel: true,
                extractComments: true
            }),
            new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({}),
            new CompressionPlugin()
        ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {loader: "style-loader"},
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            localIdentName: 'ko_[sha1:hash:hex:3]'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,       
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,         
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

[Error I get now when loading inline styles via JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkENG.png)

Comment: *"When I keep my SCSS file imported, my server is unable to start "* can you show how you are attempting to import it? without seeing the relevant source code it's hard to know why you have this problem and/or give a solution. Please update your question and include the relevant source code. Thank you.

Comment: `import styles from '../css/style.scss';` I import it, then bind it, because I have it hashed in my webpack config, and then I have a parser class to create items with the corresponding hash name.